# How to limit only two "0 and 1" strings for an xor implement?

Tags: graphics, logic

I tried to implement some logic gates for a series of "0 & 1" strings, just like *and*, *or*, *nand*, *nor* and *not* listed below. How could I limit *xor* only accept a two strings list as its argument?

```
str2 = {"11000000", "10000001", "11111111"};

or[str : {__String}] := 
  StringJoin[
   MapThread[Or, 
     Characters[str] /. {"0" -> False, "1" -> True}] /. {False -> "0", True -> "1"}];

and[str : {__String}] := 
  StringJoin[
   MapThread[And, 
     Characters[str] /. {"0" -> False, "1" -> True}] /. {False -> "0", True -> "1"}];

nand[str : {__String}] := 
  not[StringJoin[
    MapThread[ And, 
      Characters[str] /. {"0" -> False, "1" -> True}] /. {False -> "0", True -> "1"}]];

nor[str : {__String}] := 
  not[StringJoin[
    MapThread[ Or, 
      Characters[str] /. {"0" -> False, "1" -> True}] /. {False -> "0", True -> "1"}]];

not[str : _String ] := 
  StringJoin[ 
   Characters[str] /. {"1" -> False, "0" -> True}  /. {False -> "0", True -> "1"}];

(* ????? *)
xor[str : {_String, _String}] := 
  StringJoin[
   MapThread[Xor, 
     Characters[str] /. {"0" -> False, "1" -> True}] /. {False -> "0", True -> "1"}];
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble following. Could you provide an example of your desired input/output?

Comment: I suppose xor should only take two strings for its xor operation, as I used the `{_string,_string}` pattern to control the argument. The example above showed that it took str2(a three string list) as its argument with no sign of error and gave a wrong result!

Comment: @user16069 Have you tried restarting your kernel? You could have some old definition lingering that accepts more than two strings. The current definition looks right to me.

Comment: @Pickett You are right. Everything becomes normal after quitting MM and back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be simpler to implement the logic directly, with fewer transformations:

```
str2={"11000000","10000001","11111111"};

do[f_]:=StringJoin[ToString/@Boole@MapThread[f,StringSplit[#,""]]]&;

not=StringReplace[#,{"1"->"0","0"->"1"}]&;
not@str2[[1]]
```

> "00111111"

```
or=do[!FreeQ[{##},"1"]&];
or@str2
```

> "11111111"

```
and=do[FreeQ[{##},"0"]&];
and@str2
```

> "10000000"

```
nand=do[!FreeQ[{##},"0"]&];
nand@str2
```

> "01111111"

```
nor=do[FreeQ[{##},"1"]&];
nor@str2
```

> "00000000"

```
xor=do[Count[{##},"1"]==1&];
xor@str2
```

> "00111110"

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

```
xor[ab : {a_String /; StringFreeQ[a, Except["0" | "1"]], 
          b_String /; StringFreeQ[b, Except["0" | "1"]]}] := 
  StringJoin[
    MapThread[Xor, Characters[ab] /. {"0" -> False, "1" -> True}] /. 
      {False -> "0", True -> "1"}]
```

Since `xor` is limited to two strings in the list it will be convenient to support this form:

```
xor[a_String, b_String] := xor[{a, b}]
```

Some tests:

```
a = "1100"; b = "1010"; c = "1111"; d = "105a";
xor[{a, b}]
```

> ```
> "0110"
> ```

```
xor[{a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> xor[{"1100", "1010", "1111"}]
> ```

```
xor[a, b]
```

> ```
> "0110"
> ```

```
xor[a, d]
```

> ```
> xor[{"1100", "105a"}]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bitwise approach, using a two-argument definition like [@m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg):

```
xor[str1_String, str2_String] := 
  IntegerString[
   BitXor[FromDigits[str1, 2], FromDigits[str2, 2]],
   2, 
   StringLength[str1]];
```

The other functions could be implemented with bitwise operators, too.

Comment: @Karsten7. I didn't notice your deleted answer until now. If you'll undelete, I delete mine. I think it's worth showing the bitwise approach (obviously, since I did).